# Render Input & Label tags at the same DOM level with Django ChoiceInput

Tags: python, django

The default django ChoiceInput outputs the `<input>` within the `<label>` tag & I've been asked to output them at the same level in the DOM so have written a custom renderer.

The field isn't rendering safe HTML so in the browser I'm just seeing the field label, then the raw html for the choices.

I've looked over the `ChoiceFieldRenderer` which I'm inheriting & it's render function returns a `mark_safe()` string, so why does my field just render raw HTML?

My form field is declared as so;

```
class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    my_field = forms.NullBooleanField(
        widget=forms.widgets.RadioSelect(
            choices=FIELD_CHOICES,
            renderer=MyRadioFieldRenderer
        ),
        required=True,
        initial=True
    )
```

And my custom renderer;

```
class MyChoiceInput(forms.widgets.ChoiceInput):

    def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if self.id_for_label:
            label_for = format_html(' for="{0}"', self.id_for_label)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        return format_html(
            '{0}<label{1}>{2}</label>', self.tag(), label_for, self.choice_label
        )


class RadioChoiceInput(MyChoiceInput):
    input_type = 'radio'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RadioChoiceInput, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value = force_text(self.value)


class MyRadioFieldRenderer(forms.widgets.ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    choice_input_class = RadioChoiceInput
```